# Sulla frequenza dell'uso del verbo "gire"

Tags: verbs

Leggendo la [Grammatica storica della lingua e dei dialetti italiani](https://archive.org/details/grammaticastori00meyegoog), a pagina 13, mi sono trovato di fronte al verbo **gire**. Non sapendo nulla riguardo all'esistenza di tale verbo, l'ho cercato su Google e a quanto pare è un verbo in tutto e per tutto. La mia domanda è la seguente:

*In quante e quali regioni viene utilizzato, in modo significativo, il suddetto verbo?*

Comment: Personalmente, anziché Google avrei consultato uno o più vocabolari.

Comment: Ho già consultato il Treccani, ma mi dice solamente che il verbo è, appunto, usato solamente in alcune regioni, e perciò la mia domanda.

Comment: Per quanto mi riguarda *mai* sentito

Comment: A puro titolo di esempio, segnalo L. Da Ponte, le Nozze di Figaro, atto I, N. 2: "Se a caso madama la notte ti chiama: din din, in due passi da quella puoi gir".

Comment: "Gire" si usa anche nella provincia di Perugia. Ad esempio "dua gimo?" (dove andiamo?) oppure "dua è gito?" (dov'è andato?).

Comment: Si usa anche nell'area del Montefeltro, provincia di Pesaro ed Urbino, in forma dialettale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Più che una forma dialettale sembra essere una forma arcaica/letteraria del verbo "andare", personalmente non l'ho mai visto o sentito usare (tranne che da Dante)

[Gire](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/G/gire.php):

> - v.intr. (aus. essere)
> - Andare: lasciammo il muro, e gimmo in vêr lo mezzo (Dante)
> - dif., usato solo nelle forme del pres.indic. noi giamo, voi gite, in quelle dell’imperf.indic. io givo, tu givi, egli giva o gia, essi gìvano, in tutte le forme del pass.rem. e del fut.semplice indic., del pres.cond. e dell’imperf.congiunt., nel part.pass. gito e in tutti i tempi composti
>     a
>     aus. essere
> - (ant., lett.) andare: lasciammo il muro e gimmo inver’ lo mezzo (DANTE Inf. X, 134)
>     Etimologia: ← lat. īre.

(Hoepli e Garzanti)

Qui c'è un accenno a "***[gire](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dialetti-umbro-marchigiani_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)***" come forma dialettale umbro/marchigiana:

> - L'area umbro-marchigiana, anche a causa della sua conformazione ..... (sud-est), donna e femmina, ***andare e gire o ire***, ascoltare e sentire, accendere e appicciare. ....

(Treccanionline)

Comment: c'è un sostantivo derivato che è ancora molto usato: _gita_

Answer (score 5):

Si usa ancora nel dialetto della città di Potenza nelle stesse forme di Dante. Nella città di Potenza andava si dice 'gia' come nel canto XXVII dell'Inferno, 'gisse' diventa 'gess' è così via.

Comment: Interessante! Non lo sapevo. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Marche, Valle del Potenza, Cingoli, Apiro: "è gito/gitu" etc. Tutte varianti da "itus" come "jitu", a pochi chilometri.